# CompizConfig caused Unity to change

Tags: unity, compiz, launcher

After I installed CompizConfig and just clicked on an option (I don't remember which), the launcher bar disappeared completely and also the things in the upper-right corner aren't there anymore. I can't even use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>. What should I do?

Update: When I run Unity in the terminal, I get the message:

> unity-panel-service: No Process found

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You disabled Unity. If the window is still open, tick the box in front o *Unity*.
If not, switch to a terminal (CTRL+ALT+F1), login, type `unity --reset` and press enter. Then, for simplicity's sake, type `sudo reboot`, enter your password, and hit enter once more.
After it reboots, Unity should be fully functional again.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work, and when I startet CCSM, using [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears), there was the Ubuntu Unity Plugin, which wasn't activated, but when I did and restarted, nothing changed.

Comment: That's odd... Folow the guide of the link you gave me until step 3, and in stead of `ccsm`, type `gnome-terminal`. Then switch back to X (CTRL+ALT+F7), and type `unity`. Does that launch Unity again?

Comment: Yes, no it works - after I put Unity also back on in CCSM, as I put it off somewhen in the testing^^
Thanks :)